# When does the kinetochore form?

Tags: dna-replication, cell-division, cell-cycle

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetochore),

> the outer plate... is assembled in the surface of the chromosomes when the nuclear envelope breaks down.

However is makes not mention of when the inner portion of the kinetochore forms, and I cannot seem to find this jn formation elsewhere. Is it present from DNA replication and helps to hold the sister chromatids together?

Comment: Have you checked wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetochore

Comment: @FilipeRocha as you can see I referenced Wikipedia in the first line of my post. So yes, Wikipedia was my first port of call. As I stated above, it says when the outer plate of the kinetochore forms, but I do not know if the kinetochore chore exists from DNA replication in s phase. It makes no mention of this.

Comment: Oops, that's true, you did! What do you mean "exists from the DNA replication in S phase"? My idea is that the chore is also formed during mitosis, prophase , at the same time as the outer part, but I can't give you a sure answer :/

Comment: @FilipeRocha i thought that perhaps the inner core is present in s phase and prevents the sister chromatids from separating (as well as the cohesins)

Comment: That is the function of the centromere, may you be confusing the names? The inner kinetochore is the part of the kinetochore which attaches to the centromere during mitosis, but only forms then, in contrast with the centromere, which is always present, even when the chromossome is made of a single chromatid. I think historically the word "kinetochore" was used to describe the centromere, but no longer. Also the cohesins only do their function when chromatid condensation begins (prophase).

Comment: @FilipeRocha from what I am aware, the cohesins are present from the dba replication on s phase and they mostly break during chromosome condensation in mitosis.

Comment: you are right about the choesins, they are present from after the dna replication a break during anaphase